# Can anyone help me find the error with this MySQL command

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Can anyone help me find the error with this MySQL command

It show some error near start_date & "AND" & end_date

```
Using ValSql As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT SUM(adult_tickets), SUM(child_tickets), SUM(income) FROM `transaction` WHERE from_st ='" & from_st & "'" & " AND " & "to_st ='" & to_st & " AND " & "date BETWEEN'" & start_date & "AND" & end_date & "'", DBConnection)
```

Comment: do you need to make the last `"AND"` into something like `"' AND '"` so the values are quotes?

Comment: If you use SQL parameters instead of concatenating the values in the string then you won't have that problem and it will be resistant to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: As a poor substitute for doing it the right way, you could put `"SELECT SUM(adult_tickets), SUM(child_tickets), SUM(income) FROM \`transaction\` WHERE from_st ='" & from_st & "'" & " AND " & "to_st ='" & to_st & " AND " & "date BETWEEN'" & start_date & "AND" & end_date & "'"` into a variable and examine the value of it before executing the query.

Comment: To troubleshoot this kind of thing, put your constructed SQL statement into a variable and then examine it. You surely have constructed it incorrectly.  I think you're missing a `'` after `to_st`.  By the way use prepared statements and parameters for best results and security.

Comment: This appears to be yet another example of someone being told that they have a syntax error in the SQL code but not bothering to actually look at the SQL code. The VB code used to construct the SQL code is hard to read and error-prone as a result, and that's why you made the error. If you'd bothered to look at the SQL code, you'd likely have seen the error and been able to fix it. If you did it properly in the first place, i.e. not used all those concatenation operators, then you probably wouldn't have made the error in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be missing a closing quote in the SQL after the `to_st` column here:

`"to_st ='" & to_st & " AND "`

You need to add a closing single quote before the `AND`.

Alternatively, use SQL parameters like Andrew Morton suggested rather than SQL concatenation. It's a much easier and safer approach and avoids issues like this.